# Is it possible to validade oclif flags values

Tags: javascript, typescript, flags, inquirer, oclif

I want to know if it's possible to validate the flag value before the command is executed.

```
healthCheckPort: Flags.integer({
    description: 'This flag allows you to choose what port the health check sever is running on.',
    default: 6000,
    dependsOn: ['healthCheck'],
  }),
```